# Fonts are not showing up in the Export server rendered files

Tags: highcharts

I've looked all over for an answer, I've been searching since 9:00am this morning (It's currently 4:50pm as of this writing).

I'm getting no text in my charts rendered through the export server.   I setup a CentOS 6.3 machine, with Java 1.7.0_21 and Tomcat 7.  I built the application WAR file according to the instructions and setup the app on the server.

The app runs properly, and I can get the demo page to show up.  You can see it here:
http://charts.buzztown.com:8080/highcharts-export/demo

The images have no text.  Simply squares where each character should be.

I've installed fonts according to this walk through:
http://minimallinux.blogspot.com/2012/08/centos-6rhel-install-fonts.html

So the basics are definitely there. I've restarted Tomcat I don't know how many times.

Any help would be great... Thanks.

Comment: Restarting Tomcat was apparently not enough.  I restarted the whole server, and now the fonts are showing up in the generated charts.

The walk through was the right answer: http://minimallinux.blogspot.com/2012/08/centos-6rhel-install-fonts.html

Just needed the reboot after all was said and done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried this and it works.

Just repeating whatever Testero Userable has told, because generally people tend to overlook Stackoverflow comments

1. Install the fonts on your linux box from the instructions in  http://minimallinux.blogspot.com/2012/08/centos-6rhel-install-fonts.html
2. Restart you app-server and verify if it works, if this does not work then restart your machine and the export server will be able to pick up the fonts.